# How do I attach these arms to the torso?

Tags: modeling, snapping

[image: the torso and arm]

So I have made a torso and arms and I need to attach the arms to the torso. I have made sure the shape of the faces I need to snap together are identical, and they are on the same z level, so I can slide them over each other on the y axis. The only issue I have is attaching them. I am fairly new to blender so please be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You already did all the important steps. All you have left to do is move the arm into place (you could use [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping)). After the arm is aligned, simply remove doubles.
<kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*, from the 3D view header > *Mesh* > *Clean Up* > *Remove Doubles*, or from the tool shelf, tools tab *Remove Doubles*.

---

If you did not have every vertex perfectly aligned. You could select both the loop on the arm and the loop on the shoulder and [Bridge Edge Loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops).
Or you could go around selecting each vertex and its corresponding pair on the shoulder and [Merge](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merging) the vertices <kbd>M</kbd> > *At Center*, or from the 3D view header > *Mesh* > *Vertices* > *Merge* > *At Center*.

Three ways to do this, all pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you' I'll give it a go now EDIT - It worked, thank you so much

Comment: Since it worked, you should approve this as the answer.